# When decoding H264 packages which of the sprop-parameter-sets has higher priority?

Tags: h.264, rtp, sdp

I am decoding a streaming video. It is sent as RTP packages.
Before sending the video the receiver gets an SDP file that, among other things, has the `sprop parameter sets`.

However, the decoding works even if i remove that parameter. That's why I'm presuming the `sprop parameter sets` are also present in the H264 packages (in the RTP payload).

So, we can have `sprop parameter sets` on two places, which is considered the prioritized one?

Answer (score 2):

There is no priority. The sprop contains an SPS/PPS. Each SPS/PPS has an id, when needed the NALS in the stream just indicate the specific SPS/PPS it needs. It is also legal for an h.264 encoder to just repeat the same SPS/PPS in the stream for protocols that do not have a method of transmitting out of band data, and require the ability to just a stream in progress (Like over the air TV)